# how to search data in jtable using jtextfield?

Tags: java, search, netbeans, jtable

I create jtable in netbeans and populate data from database in jtable, but i am unable to implement search option in jtable using jtextfield. Can anyone please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Whatdo you mean by search option.You want to enter something in Textfield and it will highlight those rows in table or show the rows that matches the text or what..Eloborate your requirement more and post some code

Comment: Yeah exactly madhan. Can u help me?

Comment: How can i help you.Just explain what do you want I've asked two things..what i your requirement?

Comment: i already populate data from database to table and i want to enter keywords in text field then only matching  keyword shows result in table.

Comment: So the data you enter will search in all column's in all rows or particular column.

Comment: it should search in all column and display in jtable

Comment: `JTable` has a well defined and documented filtering API, see [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to search something on table you have to have original content stored in some variable.In the below example I stored the initial values of table model to a vector.
There are two implementations below.One to search as soon as you type something on textfield, other to search only after a button is clicked.

For the first one you have to use a [documentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to do things for you.

The below function will remove the table values[incase if no match found the table will be empty] and search for a string in all cells and if a match is found it will add that row to the table.

```
public void searchTableContents(String searchString) {    
  DefaultTableModel currtableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    //To empty the table before search
    currtableModel.setRowCount(0);
    //To search for contents from original table content
    for (Object rows : originalTableModel) {
        Vector rowVector = (Vector) rows;
        for (Object column : rowVector) {
            if (column.toString().contains(searchString)) {
                //content found so adding to table
                currtableModel.addRow(rowVector);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is the fullcode of the above

```
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableSearch extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Vector originalTableModel;
DocumentListener documentListener;

public TableSearch() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //backup of original values to check
    originalTableModel = (Vector) ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).getDataVector().clone();
    //add document listener to jtextfield to search contents as soon as something typed on it
    addDocumentListener();
}

private void addDocumentListener() {
    documentListener = new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            search();
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            search();
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
            search();
        }

        private void search() {
            searchTableContents(jTextField1.getText());
        }
    };
    searchOnType.setSelected(true);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    table = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    searchOnType = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    searchButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {"masd", "asdad", "asdasda", "ert"},
            {"gdfg", "name", "test", "dfg"},
            {"rrrh", "dfg", "sdfsf", "sdf"},
            {"ter", "retg", "wersd", "wer"}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table);

    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    searchOnType.setText("Search on Type");
    searchOnType.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
            searchOnTypeItemStateChanged(evt);
        }
    });

    searchButton.setText("Search");
    searchButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            searchButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 192, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(searchButton)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(searchOnType)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(searchButton)
                .addComponent(searchOnType))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void searchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    searchTableContents(jTextField1.getText());
}                                            

private void searchOnTypeItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                              
    if (searchOnType.isSelected()) {
        jTextField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
    } else {
        jTextField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(null);
    }
}                                             

public void searchTableContents(String searchString) {
    DefaultTableModel currtableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    //To empty the table before search
    currtableModel.setRowCount(0);
    //To search for contents from original table content
    for (Object rows : originalTableModel) {
        Vector rowVector = (Vector) rows;
        for (Object column : rowVector) {
            if (column.toString().contains(searchString)) {
                //content found so adding to table
                currtableModel.addRow(rowVector);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TableSearch().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JButton searchButton;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox searchOnType;
private javax.swing.JTable table;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: `JTable` has had a well defined and documented filtering API since 1.4, see [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score -1):

I create jtable with one column in eclipse and populate data from database in jtable. If Two Textfield in frame and
I enter something in Textfield1 and it will highlight those rows in table that matches the text and
those highlight row selected in jtable value show in Textfield1. And Same happen in Textfield2 at same form.